# How to add input box and submit button to add option dynamically for select box dropdown angularjs and bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

> How to add option dynamically to a select box? suppose if there is nod
>   related data to be select in selectbox there should be an option to
>   add new option using input box.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular-ui-bootstrap, use typeahead directive.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

No. 4 example should be helpful for you. And to add a new option, you have to code that manually. Beacuse, add a new option isn't available on select elements both in ui-bootstrap and angular material.